# Retrieve JSON Object from a jar file

Tags: java, runnable

I have created a runnable jar file with a JSON Object "J" as return type in a method A() of Class A. JSON Obj was in a package `a.b`. Now my question is that, When I import the jar in any other project the return type JSON obj needed to be placed in the same package path(i.e., `a.b`) provided in the jar.Else compile error occurs if the path is changed something like `a.b.c.json`. Am I following the correct procedure to retrieve JSON object or else is there any other procedure??

```
 Class A{
   public Json A(){
     return Json;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a Class definition like:

```
class A {
  public Json call() {}
}
```

This means that the class A is not visible outside it's package, because its visibility is package private. Change it to something like `public class A`, and you should be able to use it in other places.

Also, please note that the class name should be (by general convention) a constructor.